# 複数のローダブルELFを切り替えて実行しようとすると、実行できないELFファイルがある。

Tags: spresense

spresense sdk チュートリアルの、[17. ローダブルELFチュートリアル]を利用して
プログラムの自動アップデートができればと思い、以下のテストをしました。

hello worldサンプルを使用して最初にビルドした nuttx.spk を spresense へ書き込み
その後同じ環境で、そのサンプルソースを追加修正した複数パターンのELFファイルを作成し
flashへ格納後、spresense上で "nsh>/mnt/spif/hello" として動作させようとすると、
ELFファイルによっては "command not found" となり実行できないものがあります。

nuttx.spk は一度作成して書き込んだ後は、ローダブルELFだけを作成して入れ替えれば良いと
思っていたのですが、ビルド時に何か他の設定が必要なのでしょうか？
ヒントを頂ける方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

環境：Windows10, SDK2.0.1, NUTTX8.2, VSCode1.50.0

**以下のプログラムを作成してテストしました (hello_main.c だけ修正してビルド)：**

```
プログラム１ ：hello world の表示して終了
               nuttx.spk(163040 byte) : ELFファイル(4192 byte)
               
プログラム２ ：hello world の表示とmainでLEDの点滅10回して終了
               nuttx.spk(163360 byte) : ELFファイル(8684 byte)
               
プログラム３ ：hello world の表示とmain, taskA, taskBでLEDの点滅10回して終了
               nuttx.spk(163360 byte) : ELFファイル(11048 byte)
```

**起動テスト結果：**

```
プログラム１の nuttx.spk 使用時は、プログラム１が動作　２，３はエラー
プログラム２の nuttx.spk 使用時は、プログラム１、２が動作　３はエラー
プログラム３の nuttx.spk 使用時は、プログラム１、２、３が動作
```

Comment: どんなプログラムなのか判らないのでまともな回答はできないのですが、動作するELFのプログラムと、動作しないELFのプログラムを比較して、相違点を調べてみてはいかがですか？　動作の違いはコードの違いによるものでしょうから。

Comment: ビルドした時の nuttx.spk と ローダブルELF の組み合わせでは、問題なく動作します。他のビルドした時の nuttx.spk を入れた時に、動作するELFと動作しないELFがあることから nuttx.spk の問題なのではと考えています。

Comment: プログラム中で使用しているライブラリによってビルドしたときの nuttx.spk が決まるため、ビルドした時のプログラムで使用していないライブラリを使っているELFファイルは動作しないのではないかなと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nuttxのローダブルELFの仕組みをみてみましたが、ビルド時に sdk/apps/symtab_apps.c にシンボルテーブルを自動生成して、実行時にそのテーブルを参照してシンボル解決を行っているようです。組み合わせによってエラーになるのはおそらくそのアプリがシンボルテーブルに存在しない関数を使用しているためだと思います。

open/read/write/ioctl/closeのようにアプリから頻繁に使用するPOSIX関数や、それ以外にもアプリから使用する可能性のある関数については、それらがシンボルテーブルに含まれている状態でnuttx.spkを作成しておく必要があります。

言い換えると、シンボルテーブルに登録されている関数を使ったアプリ(ELF)であれば、ELFファイルを入れ替えても実行可能になると思います。

Comment: kzzさんありがとうございます。私もELFファイルのシンボルダンプで確認したところ同じ認識です。